# UnicodeDecodeError: save to file in python

Tags: python, runtime-error, decode

i want to read file, find something in it and save the result, but when I want to save it it give me a error
`UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 19: ordinal not in range(128)`

Code to save to file:
`fileout.write((key + ';' + nameDict[key]+ ';'+src + alt +'\n').decode('utf-8'))`

What can I do to fix it?
Thank you

Comment: Is this Python 2? Why are you *decoding* from UTF-8 to unicode? What is `fileout` exactly? What's in your variables?

Comment: It is python 2 and in variables are img tags parsed with BeautifulSoup

Comment: So `key`, `nameDict[key]`, `src` and `alt` are **all** values from BeautifulSoup? Those values are unicode then.

Comment: `key` and `nameDict[key]` are from other file. I figure out that is error in nameDict[key] and it can`t save name "Bartolomé"

Comment: Then first *decode* that data to Unicode first. Do you know the encoding used for that file? Your best option is to use `io.open()` for that file.

Comment: @Allda, the answers you seek are in [this presentation](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html).

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to concatenate unicode values with byte strings, then turn the result to unicode, to write it to a file object that most likely only takes byte strings.

*Don't mix unicode and byte strings like that*.

Open the file to write to with [`io.open()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.open) to automate encoding Unicode values, then handle **only** unicode in your code:

```
import io

with io.open(filename, 'w', encoding='utf8') as fileout:
    # code gathering stuff from BeautifulSoup

    fileout.write(u'{};{};{}{}\n'.format(key, nameDict[key], src, alt)
```

You may want to check out the [`csv` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) to handle writing out delimiter-separated values. If you do go that route, you'll have to explicitly encode your columns:

```
import csv

with open(filename, 'wb') as fileout:
    writer = csv.writer(fileout, delimiter=';')
    # code gathering stuff from BeautifulSoup

    row = [key, nameDict[key], src + alt]
    writer.writerow([c.encode('utf8') for c in row])
```

If some of this data comes from other files, make sure you also *decode* to Unicode first; again, `io.open()` to read these files is probably the best option, to have the data decoded to Unicode values for you as you read.